# Upon submitting sign up form, ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a sign up form on rails, and upon clicking my submit button to save my user details, I get the following error:

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

for this line: `@user = User.new(params[:user])`in my users controller.

See code below:

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new 
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "You signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]= "valid"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
      flash[:color]= "invalid"
    end
    render "new"
  end
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_for(:user, :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
    </br> <%= f.text_field :firstname, placeholder: 'First Name' %> 
    </br> <%= f.text_field :lastname, placeholder: 'Last Name' %>
    </br> <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: 'Email' %> 
    </br> <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: 'Password' %>
    </br> <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: 'Confirm Password' %>
    <%= f.submit :Register %>
  <% end %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <ul class="Signup_Errors">
    <% for message_error in @user.errors.full_messages %>
      <li>* <%= message_error %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/new'

  get 'pages/home'

  get 'pages/howitworks'

  get 'pages/about'

  get 'pages/contact'

  get 'pages/becomeauser'

  get 'signup' => 'users#new'

  resources :users
```

Answer (score 0):

The `params[:user]` hash might have attributes in it that isn't a part of the User model. In your case, i'm guessing its password_confirmation.

Use strong params the next time - [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new 
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "You signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]= "valid"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
      flash[:color]= "invalid"
    end

    render "new"
  end
end

private:

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, : password)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have [Strong Parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) enabled. I would encourage you to read at least a part of [this Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters). Essentially, instead of using `params[]` to update or create records, you should use an intermediate method to ensure that users aren't sneaking information into your requests. This is much safer. For instance, someone could submit a "created_at" attribute with your form, and then be modifying fields which are not supposed to be edited. Your approach should instead be as follows:

1. Create a private user_params method *in the controller* which permits specified attributes

   ```
   private

       def user_params
         params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
       end
   ```
2. Replace your `User.create()`, `User.new()`, and `User.update()` references to `params[:user]` with `user_params`

   ```
   # Do this instead of @user = User.new(params[:user])
   @user = User.new(user_params)
   ```